# Optional injection in EJB3 bean or runtime dependency checks

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, annotations, ejb-3.0

I want to define injection so that only if the injected interface has EJB it will be injected. This is used as a plug-in to the main EJB. How to do this? Is there some annotation for this?

I can use @PostConstruct to manually "inject" the variable. But then I have to handle the dependencies by myself. How can I handle dependencies knowing that one of them is optional? How do I handle the order of deployment of different dependent modules.

**Update:**
I see that google has an inject annotation with `optional` parameter:

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
@Inject(optional = true)
```

**Update 2:**
JBoss has something that may be what I'm looking for:

```
import org.jboss.annotation.IgnoreDependency;
@IgnoreDependency @EJB OtherBean otherBean;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity. What is the use of this? Why make it optional?

Comment: To implement some kind of plug-in module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution would be to use JNDI and not injection in this particular case. That way I have full control over the dependencies.